# How to create different XML for Different categories in Amazon Seller API?

Tags: amazon-mws, amazon-selling-partner-api, amazonsellercentral

I need to create new product to amazon Seller account through API. but when it comes to product categories and sub categories, the XML is different for different category. How to create that different XML files for different categories and sub-categories.

Also in the documentation, the sample XML given for update feed. I also need to how the structure of XML would be when we create a new product to amazon seller account through an API. Can anyone help to solve this issue.